# Check if each file in a list (which is in a file) exists in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file (ListOfAllFiles.txt) that has a list of 500 files some of which exist and some don't.

I'd like to make two texts files that indicate which files exist and which don't.

This is my code thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash


for f in $(cat /path/to/ListOfAllFiles.txt)
do
  if [[ -f $f ]]; then 
     echo $f > /path/to/FilesFound.txt
  else
     echo $f > /path/to/FilesNOTFound.txt
  fi
done
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that each pass through the loop will overwrite either `/path/to/FilesFound.txt` or `/path/to/FilesNOTFound.txt`; instead of using `>`, you should be using `>>`. Fixing that, and making other improvements for robustness, we get:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n > /path/to/FilesFound.txt     # reset to empty file
echo -n > /path/to/FilesNOTFound.txt  # reset to empty file

while IFS= read -r f ; do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then 
     echo "$f" >> /path/to/FilesFound.txt
  else
     echo "$f" >> /path/to/FilesNOTFound.txt
  fi
done < /path/to/ListOfAllFiles.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  When I do this, the two files are created  (FilesFound.txt and FilesNOTFound.txt) however nothing is written to them...

Comment: @Sheila: Are you sure that `/path/to/ListOfAllFiles.txt` exists and contains what you think it does? (What does `head /path/to/ListOfAllFiles.txt` print?)

Comment: Yes it exists.  I just opened ListOfAllFiles.txt to double check and it prints the full path to each file, with one file per line.

Comment: @Sheila: And does `head /path/to/ListOfAllFiles.txt` print what you expect? (Make sure the path is correct, including the `/`; make sure that you have uppercase and lowercase in the correct places; etc.)

Comment: Ah yes - I realized all the lines in ListOfALlFiles.txt were not on the same line when using the 'head' command.  Thanks for your help!